# Jenkins update restore

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I don't know what happened but I guess Jenkins has been auto updated from my system it redirected me to its installation setup and now my old account setup has gone my all old files are there with me I just don't know how to restore my old setup please help!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of jenkins home directory with the old files, replace the existing home directory with this backup and restart the jenkins server. This should restore all of your old setup